# How to make an AJAX call to different domains in Ruby on Rails 3.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I have an action `email` in my controller of application running on www.example.com and I am trying to send the form data of `email` to `www.data.example.com/email` where my another application receives the request and I am able to save the data in `js` format. But I want to send back the acknowledgement to www.example.com and replace the html using `rjs` template. Here are some code for you reference:

> **email.html.erb** called on ***www.example.com***

```
   <div id="div_content">
    <%= form_for(@user, :url => "http://data.example.com/mail", :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email%>
    <% end %>
   </div>
```

> **email** action of application on : data.example.com/email -

```
def email
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save!
       format.html { redirect_to(user_page_path(@user.vip_id), :notice => 'Thank you! You are now on our priority list.') }
       format.js
    else
       format.html { render :text => "user can not be saved at this moment!"}
    end
  end
end
```

> **email.js.rjs** called on **www.data.example.com/email**

```
page.replace_html :div_content, :partial => "show", :object => @user
```

I can see in my log that request comes all the way from one domain to sub domain and even action gets triggered but, I can not get the response back to the main domain. So, is there any way to send a callback to main domain. I just want to reflect changes there at the form which is inside `div_content` div and want to replace with content of `_show.html.erb` which I have on my sub domain.

Many Thanks,
Surya :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys here is what I got to make it work -

Well I was trying to do cross domain communication using my both RoR app as I mentioned right up there in my question!

Finally I have found a way to achieve the same using "EasyXDM" (www.easyxdm.net) it solved the problem. It works great on most of the browsers including IE7 and Firefox older versions.
CORS is another solution if you want to get it done, but it fails to work on IE7...

whoa! now I can rely on the cross domain communication between my different apps without using an iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because rails thinks you are trying to launch a cross site request forgery attack against yourself. By default rails has a security feature baked in that rejects form submission from outside sources (ie your other app)

Easiest (but not the most secure), way around it would be to add this to the top of the controller you are posting the data to:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :email
```

RE COMMENTS

Ahh I see, I was not paying very close attention when I first read your post, sorry about that. I missed all the parts about rjs.

I am certainly no expert on rjs but it looks like you are doing most everything right. Only suspicious part to me is this line:

```
page.replace_html :div_content, :partial => "show", :object => @user
```

I think it should be:

```
page.insert_html(:bottom, "div_content", :partial => "show")
```

Also you might want to try and replace the rjs template with

```
page.alert("debug");
```

Just to make sure its really not coming back, because I would suspect it is...

Comment: I appreciate your quick response but here it is not the case. I am receiving the data as I wanted and it is also getting saved in my db of sub domain app. What I want is to get some response back to my main domain app where I want to update the content in a specific div. Any idea regarding this??

Comment: ya then the problem is probably with your ajax code / how you are responding in your controller (i see one problem there already). post up your javascript and i'll have a look

Comment: I am using rjs for handling all this.  I is there any other way to do it? Any link or reference to achieve the same will be very helpful.. :)

Comment: It is not working buddy :( is there any way to call two function at the same time when I click on form submit button? or execute any javascript based on event? and thanks again for your response :)